# How to troubleshoot NotSupportedException: "Assembly does not contain a script with hash code" in Kentico 6.0?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit, kentico, notsupportedexception

We are in the process of upgrading our Kentico installations from v5.5 R2 to version 6.0. The site is running, but we are running into an issue loading a Telerik control and are receiving the following error message:

```
Assembly "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" does not contain a script with hash code "ea597d4b".

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Assembly "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" does not contain a script with hash code "ea597d4b".

Source Error: 


    Line 18: {
    Line 19: // Ensure script manager
    Line 20: PortalHelper.EnsureScriptManager(Page);
    Line 21: }
    Line 22: }

Source File: d:\Websites\staging_coronapubliclibrary\CMSPages\ScriptManager.aspx.cs Line: 20 

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: Assembly "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" does not contain a script with hash code "ea597d4b".]
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.DeserializeScriptEntries(String serializedScriptEntries, Boolean loaded) +1088
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OutputCombinedScriptFile(HttpContext context) +1005
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnInit(EventArgs e) +66
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +133
System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +277
CMS.UIControls.AbstractCMSPage.EnsureScriptManager() +202
CMSPages_ScriptManager.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Websites\staging_coronapubliclibrary\CMSPages\ScriptManager.aspx.cs:20
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +105
CMS.UIControls.AbstractCMSPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +16
CMS.UIControls.CMSPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +87
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +133
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1970
```

The resource being requested is:

http://staging.coronapubliclibrary.org/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=sm1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a387126a6-cbc0-46b4-b6ca-c8de25a0044f%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Setting the EnableScriptCombine to "false" on the RadScriptManager control seems to do the trick.

Comment: Josh, feel free to add your comment as an answer, it'll make it more clear to others that come across the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this issue:

1. To fix this, set the "EnableScriptCombine" attribute to "false" on the RadScriptManager control.
2. Instead of using the RadScriptManager, you can use the ASP.NET toolkit script manager in its place, using the same ID attribute as shown below:

`<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Release" />`